# Some Css Not Working in IE8 Browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have create a template. I have used bootstrap. My template not working col-md width, :before, :after & background image in IE8 browser.

I have used in header section bellow:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 8]>        <html class="ie8 " lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>        <html class="ie9 " lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
    <title>Duranto Html Portfolio Template</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is not compatible with IE8 in many ways, but mostly for the following two reasons:

1. Pseudo classes such as :before, :after, >, etc. are poorly supported in IE8.
2. the order of multiple classes are not guaranteed. Bootstrap uses a lot of the following:

   ```
   <div class="col-md xs col12 etc etc etc">...
   ```

Comment: There are problems in IE8 with pseudos :before and :after but that's far from _poor_ support. `>` is supported (since IE7). Combined multiple classes selectors are supported since IE7. Bootstrap [supports IE8 with following informations](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9).

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer @FelipeAls. Appreciated!